# Do you need to exponentiate an inverse hyperbolic sine

Tags: regression, logarithm

I have the following model:

Yi = β1 +  εi

whereby Y is the inverse hyperbolic sine of the proportion of i county that is under the poverty threshold and β1 is a binary treatment variable. If I end up with the coefficient -0.32, would the interpretation be that the presence of the treatment decreases the proportion of the population under the poverty threshold by 32% or would I have to exponentiate the coefficient first before I make the multiplicative interpretation?

Comment: Neither.  The interpretation literally is that the presence of the treatment decreases the $\sinh^{-1}$ of the proportion by $0.32.$  That cannot be expressed as a percent change, because it isn't one: the percent change varies with the proportion.